# Why has open-iscsi two times slower writes than Samba via 10G Ethernet?

Tags: iscsi, software-raid, mdadm, raid5, open-iscsi

On my local file server I have raid-6 on 7x HDD drives.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=2048 conv=fdatasync
```

Local speed test gives me 349 MB/s write speed.

Remote writes to Samba from SSD (>2Gb/s read speed) gives me 259 MB/s writes.
But remote writes to iSCSI drive (on Win10 iSCSI initiator) gives me mere 151 Mb/s writes.

raid6 config - 128K chunk size, stripe_cache_size = 8191. Write intent bitmap is on SSD (Samsung 860 PRO, 4096K bitmap chunk).

Array mounted with options: `rw,noatime,nobarrier,commit=999,stripe=128,data=writeback`

open-iscsi setup: target is based on a 4Tb file.

Any hints why iSCSI is slower than Samba on writes?
Any hints on how to improve iSCSI writes speed?

I assume it has something to do with the desire of open-iscsi to flush writes to disk after each operation, which increases write amplification on raid6 due to excessive parity rewrites. But I am not sure how to fix it. Speed it more important than safety of currently written data in case of power outage.

As a side note older ietd iSCSI target had the ability to enable write-back mode (using  `IOMode=wb`) and the sustained write speed was much faster. Unfortunately it seems to be currently unmaintained.

Comment: What is the network like ? 10GigE? What's the server OS version, kernel version? What is the iscsi target and version? ietd, scst or lio? Open-iscsi only provides an initiator, not a  target...  What are you using to measure write speed? What is the filesystem used on the target?

Comment: In the Windows 10, QoS removed from the NIC ?

Comment: Posting the configuration of your iSCSI target and any adjusted network tunables would also be prudent in this case. You might also consider testing with an open-iscsi initiator on a linux client with a modern kernel to give a clear comparison between initiators using the same target, since the existing test might be narrowed too much by the Windows initiator. More data == more better.

Comment: But as far as the *actual* question is concerned: iSCSI and Samba are very different, and you're utilizing a VFS caching layer when using Samba that doesn't exist in a bare block device. I understand that you're surprised by the differences in performance, but do you care more about this comparison, or getting iSCSI to saturate your network? If iSCSI is your chief concern and Samba performance is a minor detail for context, you might edit the question to make that more clear (and probably get better answers).

Comment: You used a Windows 10 for the test, but I don't see any detail of the machine used anywhere. (and why using a Windows client OS for such test?)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the RAID-6 is the problem because of the double parity calculation. Secondly, you can connect iSCSI target twice in MS iSCSI Initiator, enable RR or Least Queue Depth (unfortunately, Win10 doesn't support multipathing, so you can test it with Windows Server instead).

In fact, block level access must be faster than file level access. What kind of benchmarking tool you are using from the Windows site? I would recommend using diskspd or FIO.
Additionally, you can use something like Starwind as a much faster iSCSI target.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san#Hyper-V

Comment: Raid 6 is in hardware - not software. It is no longer a performance issue since about 20 years.

Comment: RAID-6 is the problem? Parity calculations happens regardless of protocol.

Comment: RAID6 is slower not because of a parity calculations, but because of a so-called “write hole” being a result of a read-modify-write parity RAID nature.

Comment: "Raid 6 is in hardware - not software. It is no longer a performance issue since about 20 years. – Nils Mar 21 at 10:05" --> This is simply not true :( Read this --> https://theithollow.com/2012/03/21/understanding-raid-penalty/

Answer (score 1):

iSCSI should be used on block level, your setup description sounds like you are using a file-system, placing a file on it and then running this file as iSCSI block layer.

This is far from being ideal, and definiteley not a setup for comparing speeds. Try using lvm on top of the raid6 for segmenting the space and staying on block layer for iSCSI, or use raid6 directly as iSCSI device.

In your current setup, data is transferred through the network, hitting a file in the filesystem, which is (most likely) not optimized for this type of workload, and as well shared with other processes. It is possible to do such setup with iSCSI, but should be considered as unoptimized fallback solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware `dd` is a very simple benchmark and is VERY prone to distortions. For example, your `dd` is writing zeroes - if something has a special case for data full of zeroes (e.g. because it can do compression) you will see fantastic performance but switch to writing non-zero "real data" and suddenly that performance can disappear...

In order to answer your question (as in all benchmarking) you have really have to isolate the pieces to identify the bit introducing the issue. For example, is writing to the Windows filesystem directly (and not over iSCSI) also extremely fast? If you take the same hardware configuration and run Linux instead of Windows is it just as fast or does it slow down? What happens if you switch to using a benchmark tool like [fio](https://github.com/axboe/fio)?

Sadly there are too many possibilities to be able to answer a question like this well...